# Did Kino no Tabi (2017 Remake) ever release a soundtrack?

Tags: kinos-journey

I have been searching for a full soundtrack somewhere to at least purchase but I'm getting no results. Maybe that speaks for itself and tells me that it was not released, but I figured I should ask here before giving up. Anyone know something about it? Or should I give up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of current writing (June 2019), **no, *Kino no Tabi* (2017) hasn't released its OST yet**.

From [the anime's official site (Japanese)](https://www.kinonotabi-anime.com/products/music/), the only product listed in the Music category is the OP&ED CD and the limited-edition DVD (which contains the MV for *here and there*).